# Initializing select value in nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having trouble properly initializing the select boxes in a form, built with nested ng-repeats.  I have parent table rows built with an ng-repeat, and a select box whose value is bound to an attribute in the parent row.  The values in the select box are pulled from a nested child array, constituting available selections for the row.

```
 <tr ng-repeat="asv in asvs">
   <td>{{asv.scenario_asv_id}}</td>
   <td>{{asv.asv_target_id}}</td>
   <td><select ng-model="asv.asv_target_id">
       <option ng-repeat="version in asv.asv_targets"
                value="{{version.asv_target_id}}"
                ng-selected="asv.asv_target_id == version.asv_target_id">
                   ID: {{version.asv_target_id}} - Name: {{version.asv_target_desc}}
                   </option>
       </select>
       </td>
 </tr>
```

In my Plunker, you'll see that the first 2 selects initialize properly, yet the 3rd does not.  Can someone advise how to implement this properly?

https://plnkr.co/edit/NGcEMNSHCDAYK8UBOKYl

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you use ng-options with select elements. Please replace your select code with the example below:

```
<select convert-to-number
ng-options="version.asv_target_id as  ('ID: ' + version.asv_target_id + ' - Name: ' + version.asv_target_desc) for version in asv.asv_targets track by version.asv_target_id" 
ng-model="asv.asv_target_id">
</select>
```

Because your value is numeric you will have to add the following directive as per https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/api/ng/directive/select

```
module.directive('convertToNumber', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val) {
        return val != null ? parseInt(val, 10) : null;
      });
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(val) {
        return val != null ? '' + val : null;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem happening here is during the creation of select options using ng-repeat

```
  {
        "scenario_asv_asv_target_id": "16150-CI101592-3475",
        "scenario_asv_id": 16150,
        "appl_ci_id": "CI101592",
        "asv_target_id": 3475,
        "asv_target_desc": "Default General Purpose",
      }
```

If you move your data which are going to match your criteria to the end of the json, your value will get selected.

Because in the loop the select option is getting created,so it resets the already created ng-select values.

For example, I have moved the option which are going to be by default to the end of json set and the value is getting selected.

This is not recommended, for understandging.
Check into the plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/G83l6OdIfr5vlNgMSeR7?p=preview

I haven't edited your code, i have just replaced your data set.

So,

you should use ng-options as follows

```
   <tr ng-repeat="asv in asvs">
       <td>{{asv.scenario_asv_id}}</td>
       <td>{{asv.asv_target_id}}</td>
       <td>
       <select ng-model="asv.asv_target_id" 
       ng-options="version.asv_target_id as version.asv_target_desc for version in asv.asv_targets" 
       ng-selected="true">

           </select>
           </td>
     </tr>
```

final code
https://plnkr.co/edit/w8nOENAiL72SX68L7LVv?p=preview

disclaimer:
I have concentrate on explaining and helping you to select default option, so don't expect me to prettify the option data by appending data and desc in it. Do it on your own.